# Does limit of $\tan(n !)-n!,n\to \infty$ exists ?And what is its upper bound?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, upper-lower-bounds

I have tried many times to show if $\tan(n !)-n!$  exist or not but I can't , I have used this idea $n! = e(-1)^{n+1}/(n+1) + O(1/n^2) (\mod \mathbb Z)$ implies that $\tan( n!)-n!= e((-1)^{n+1}/(n+1) + O(1/n^2)) -1)(\mod \mathbb Z)$ to get such bounds of that sequence but it doesn' seems clear to me whethere it is converge or diverge , Then my question here is :Does limit of $\tan(n !)-n!$ exists ?And what is its upper bound? Wolfram alpha dosn't give any result only series asymptotic at infty as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%28+tan%28n%21%29-n%21%29%2C+n+to+infty+&wal=header)

using mathematica code  for $n=400$,  $\tan(n!)-n!$ I have got the below plot and this is the code ,

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 800},
  lst = Table[Tan[n!] - n!, {n, 0, 400}];
  ListPlot[N[Accumulate[lst], 200], PlotRange -> All]
  ]
```

**Edit:** Probabliy from density $n ! \bmod \mathbb{Z}$ the sequence would be diverge we may add this partial question :Does it will be diverge to $-\infty$ or just diverge ?

[image]

**Related question:**

https://mathoverflow.net/q/361945/51189

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \tan(n!)-n!$ exists?

Comment: yes , I seek if this limit exist or no for n go to infty

Comment: Gotcha, so then the question is morally equivalent to figuring out how well $(2k+1)\pi/2$ is approximable by $n!$.